# MacOS unified logging: how can I filter messages based on tag on the command line?

Tags: logs

I can add a message to the macos system log via the command line on Sierra or later as follows:

```
logger -t "TestTag" "testing 1 2 3"
```

How do I find all messages that have been tagged with `TestTag`?

I can use `log stream` but I can't find how to filter for that tag.  Any other command line solution would be fine too.

Comment: What MacOS version?

Comment: I tried it on MacOS Catalina, 'Tags' does not shows on log stream, just the message. Also not showing on graphical Console.app. But the message shows on both, and I know how to filter it using 'log stream' but this would not be the correct answer since you asked for the 'tag' filter. That is why I asked for your MacOS version, because 'tag' is invisible anywhere on my system version

Comment: @Prado I'm looking for >= Sierra

Comment: This works to filter by the message content: `log stream --predicate 'eventMessage contains "testing"'` but I cannot find the tag string anywhere on the unified log system. I am checking why the 'tag' string is not being logged on my system.

Comment: Tag parameter is being ignored, I tested it on Mojave and Catalina, and the message inserted on the log database is always tagged with [logger]

Comment: I think the closer it can get is filtering for 'logger' process: `log stream --info --predicate 'process == "logger"'`, it looks like 'tag' is being completely ignored by the Unified Log system. But if you try `logger -is -t "TestTag" "testing 1 2 3"` (using -is parameter) the tag is shown on terminal, but still not logged to database. Log database always logs it as [logger] message

Comment: @Prado that's a shame - that means that tagging is effectively broken and useless.  I wonder why it exists?